# Other way to check trigger action on Firebird RDBMS

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird

Is there other way to check Firebird trigger action (`insert`, `update`, `delete`) than using context variable `INSERTING`, `UPDATING`, or `DELETING`?

```
IF (INSERTING) THEN
BEGIN
/* do something */
END
```

Comment: I am curious as to why you would want a different way, could you give more background as to why? Maybe with more explanation people can come up with better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other way is to have different triggers for thоse actions

Answer (score 1):

You can write different triggers for the different actions - but within the trigger there is no other way to identify the calling action than using the context variables.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger_bef_del FOR mytable
ACTIVE BEFORE DELETE POSITION 0
As
BEGIN
  ..
END

CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger_bef_upd FOR mytable
ACTIVE BEFORE UPDATE POSITION 0
As
BEGIN
  ..
END
```